# loops to convert fahrenheit to celsius

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

This program's objective is to generates Fahrenheit temperatures from -40F to 120F and their equivalent Celsius temperatures. My two issues are getting each line in the table to be 5 degrees F more than the previous one and correctly setting up the min and max temps.

Here is my code:

```
package converter;

import java.util.*;
public class converter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double fahrenheit, celsius = 0;
        while (celsius >= -40 && <= 120 ) {
          fahrenheit = (9.0/5.0 * celsius) + 32;
          System.out.println( "Fahrenheit:" + " " + fahrenheit + " " + "Celsius:" + " " + celsius);
          celsius++;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are using `9.0/5.0` instead of just `1.8`?

Comment: `while (celsius >= -40 && <= 120 ) {` would not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

*.....is to generates fahrenheit temperatures from -40F to 120F* : So you need to vary fahrenheit from -40 to 120, therefore initialize F to -40.

```
double fahrenheit = -40, celsius = 0;
```

and

```
while ( fahrenheit <= 120 )
```

*and their equivalent Celsius temperatures* : So you calculate celsius from Fahrenheit.

```
celsius = (5.0/9.0) * ( fahrenheit - 32 )
```

and increment fahrenheit as :

```
fahrenheit++;
```

overall:

```
    double fahrenheit = -40, celsius = 0;
    while ( fahrenheit <= 120 ) {
      celsius = (5.0/9.0) * ( fahrenheit - 32 );
      System.out.println( "Fahrenheit:" + " " + fahrenheit + " " + "Celsius:" + " " + celsius);
      fahrenheit++;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! These do come out fairly long. How do I go about limiting the decimal places? Something like %.1f?

Comment: Yes could use `System.out.printf`. e.g. `System.out.printf( "Fahrenheit = %.2f", F );
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.printf( "Celsius = %.2f", C);
    System.out.println();`